# Imputing new axis tick labels using seqrplot command

Tags: r, traminer

I'm using the R packages TraMineR to compute and analyze state sequences. 
I'm trying to plot with `seqrplot` command and to change the x axis tick labels. 
The code would be, for example:

```
library("TraMineR")
data("mvad")
mvad.alphab <- c("employment", "FE", "HE", "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad, 17:86, xtstep = 6, alphabet = mvad.alphab)
mvad.dist<-seqdist(mvad.seq, method="DHD")

seqrplot(mvad.seq, dist.matrix = mvad.dist,
         criterion = "density", nrep = 1, title = "End CS qualification",
         border = NA, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at = c(1, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54,60,66,70), 
     labels = c(1, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54,60,66,70))
```

The x axis disappears but the new axis with the imputed thick values appears somewhere at the very bottom right of the plot. In other words, it doesn't replace the deleted axis. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that by default `seqrplot` (as other plot functions of the `seq?plot` family) automatically displays the color legend together with the plot, and uses `layout` to organize the plot and the legend in a single graphic. If you want to act on the axes, you should disable the automatic legend by setting `withlegend = FALSE`, and then display the legend my hand. For example:

```
opar <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
seqrplot(mvad.seq, dist.matrix = mvad.dist,
         criterion = "density", nrep = 1, title = "End CS qualification",
         border = NA, axes=FALSE, withlegend=F)
axis(1, at = c(1, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66, 70), 
     labels = c(1, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66, 70))
seqlegend(mvad.seq)
par(opar)
```

Comment: Now it works. Thank you, I'll take it into account using also other `seq?plot` commands.